# Change Mouseenter and Mouseleave to Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I have a element which shows up when you hover with a mouse. Now we want to change this to click and not mouseenter or -leave. What we have:

```
$('#element').mouseenter(function(){
$(this).stop().animate({'left': '0px'}, 500);
}).mouseleave(function(){
$(this).stop().animate({'left': -($('#element').width()-10)}, 500);
});
```

The HTML

```
<div class="element" id="element"> </div>
```

The CSS

```
.element {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

We tried to change it to this, but this doesn't work:

```
$('#element').click(function(){
$(this).stop().animate({'left': '0px'}, 500);
}).mouseleave(function(){
$(this).stop().click({'left': -($('#element').width()-10)}, 500);
});
```

We just want to slide open on click and slide back out on click again, and not on mouseevent like it is now.

Comment: have you tried it? try it and see if it works

Comment: you want it to be "click and click" or "click and mouseleave"?

Comment: also, share some HTML so we can have a better idea of what does it when you click on the element

Comment: @epascarello click and click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use a boolean to know if it's in the visible position then toggle the boolean, `var left=false;`.

```js
var left = false;
$('#element').click(function() {
  if (left) {
    $(this).stop().animate({
      'left': '0px'
    }, 500);
    left=false;
  } else {
    $(this).stop().animate({
      'left': -($('#element').width() - 10)
    }, 500);
    left=true;
  }
});
```

```css
.element {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element" id="element">Element</div>
```

An alternate method is to use jquery to get the position and animate it based on position, `$(this).position().left`

```js
$('#element').click(function() {
  if ($(this).position().left!=0) {
    $(this).stop().animate({
      'left': '0px'
    }, 500);
  } else {
    $(this).stop().animate({
      'left': -($('#element').width() - 10)
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

```css
.element {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element" id="element">Element</div>
```